# How to set defalut -webkit-line-camp css for all browser not custom css?

Tags: html, css, browser

Our require : User can enter lots of text in div but display only two line .
If text set in more than two line , automatically `overflow:hidden` and display 
three dots .

And If the text set in less than  equally two line, not require to text hidden and  display three dots in end of box.

```
.lineCamp{text-overflow: ellipsis;  
display:-webkit-box;  
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;  
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
-webkit-box-pack: center;  
overflow-wrap: break-word;}
```

Comment: No way in css for cross browser else using custom css. But there is a js way using clamp.js explained here https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: http://dev.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/